# Can a VMWare fusion image on windows 7 be legally used on more than one mac?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, macbook-pro, vmware-fusion, imac

I have a legal, store-bought copy of Windows 7.  I'd like to install it into a virtual machine, either VMWare or Parallels.

I have VMWare Fusion on my Macbook Pro and my iMac.

My question is, once this VM is configured and activated, can I copy the VM to the second Mac and run it in the second mac's VMWare. activated and legally?

Comment: Simultaneously or sequentially?

Comment: Legally you can probably only use one copy at a time.

Comment: "Legal" may vary depending on jurisdiction, but I'm fairly certain this violates Microsoft's EULA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The [Windows 7 Home Basic EULA](http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/UseTerms/Default.aspx) says

> 2. INSTALLATION AND USE RIGHTS.
>      a. One Copy per Computer. You may install one copy of the software on **one computer**. 
>      That computer is the “licensed computer.”
>      b. Licensed Computer. You may use the software on
>      up to two processors on the licensed computer at one time. Unless
>      otherwise provided in these license terms, **you may not use the
>      software on any other computer**.
>      c. Number of Users. Unless otherwise
>      provided in these license terms, only one user may use the software at
>      a time.

If you have very deep pockets you could ask your lawyers to discuss with Microsoft lawyers whether you are legally bound by the above.